# No module named pyVim

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ansible

I am running Catalina MacOS with python 3.7.5.  I am trying to run an ansible script to install a VM.  This Requires python >= 2.6 and PyVmomi.  I have installed PyVomi and pyVim via pip.  Both were installed successfully.  When I run the playbook, I get the error message below.  Not sure what I am missing.

```
TASK [Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname] *************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named pyVim
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (PyVmomi) on MacBook-Pro.local's Python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location"}
```

Comment: [Megan Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9887669/megan-bailey) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081394/12695027) saying "not sure if you've found a solution yet. But this helped me https://josephharding.github.io/tutorials/2018/07/03/ansible-modules-brew.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

pip3 install ansible

That made ansible use python3

Answer (score 10):

ArunJose_Intel is correct. The module is pyvmomi, not pyVim. Although the error indicates that the pyVim library was missing. It was misleading as I could see it in my directory. Following his advice I changed the pip install command to install pyvmomi instead.

*pip install pyvmomi*

I was able to run the python script with pyVim imported. Thank you Arun.

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed PyVomi and pyVim for the wrong python executable. You have to make sure you are installing via pip to the right python. You are installing the packages to the python3.x present in your machine. What you have to do is to install the pip packages to the python of the playbook

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion.  I have installed this via pip3, is yes they are installed in the python3 directories.

```
pip3 install PyVmomi
Requirement already satisfied: PyVmomi in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (6.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from PyVmomi) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from PyVmomi) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->PyVmomi) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->PyVmomi) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->PyVmomi) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->PyVmomi) (2.8)

pip3 install pyVim
Requirement already satisfied: pyVim in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyVim) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyVim) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyVim) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyVim) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyVim) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->pyVim) (0.1.7)
```

Comment: NO.  I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Apparently Ansible is still trying to use python 2.7 when I am on Python 3.7.5.

Comment: This seems to be part of your Question. Perhaps you should edit it into that instead of having it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

works, on top of

pip3 install PyVmomi;
pip3 install pyVim;
pip3 install ansible;

Comment: Please don't repeat answers or add "thank you" answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).